# Get value of text except some symbol (regexp)

Tags: regex

How to get value of input except `;` symbol?

regexp:

```
\<[a-z]+ .*value=([^;]+).* \/\>
```

text:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pic" value=";10giddw" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language and why not use a parser?

Comment: @hwnd, python, but it doesn't matter. I do not use a parser because I need to get only one value of one input.

Comment: @hwnd, thank you but symbol (;) can be elsewhere.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want the output to be the input with the `;` deleted or everything from the beginning up to the `;`. Or perhaps you're looking for the string after `;` contained in double quotes. Please post what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the regex you're looking for is one that captures the contents of the `value` attribute but excludes the semicolon (`;`), so you need something like

```
"<.+value=\"([^;]*?)(?:;([^;]*?))?\".*\/>"g
```

[Demo on RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/zO7iW4/3)

Explanation of the important bits:

- `([^;]*?)` lazily captures any non-semicolon characters, meaning that it stops at the first opportunity.
- `(?:;([^;]*?))?` A non-capturing group containing:

  - `;` matches a semicolon
  - `([^;]*?)` Another lazy capture group for non-semicolon characters
  - `?` The entire group is optional. It can exist or it can not exist.

These two groups capture all the characters between the quotes after `value` except for a semicolon. Note that this doesn't work in its current form if there is more than one semicolon in the `value` property.

Comment: It's really amazing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer is "use a parser". For regex, three options.

**Option 1: `\K` in Perl, PCRE (PHP, R, Notepad++), Ruby 2+...**

```
value=";\K[^"]+
```

The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns.

**Option 2: Lookbehind in the Above and Most Other Engines**

```
(?<=value=";)[^"]+
```

The lookbehind `(?<=value=";)` asserts that what precedes the current position is `value=";`, but doesn't match it.

**Option 3: Capture Group in JavaScript (and all other engines)**

```
value=";([^"]+)
```

The parentheses capture the value to Group 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for including an explanation of your answer!